# Screen resolution

Tags: android

Actually i have created an array of buttons,now my question is whether it will be fit in all screen resolution or not..as i have use nexus s device and the here its working fine..i mean to say that all the buttons are arranged in perfect order..more ever when i placed background image to each buttons its work fine..now i doubt whether it works for cheaper device by the same code i have written or i have to do something extra for that.thats means whether it fit for all screen resolution..or not..the code i have written is..

```
            LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
            LinearLayout rowLayout=null;

            LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);

            //Create Button
            for (i = 0; i<6; i++){
                rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
                layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);

                for(j=0;j<7;j++){
                    pBtnDay[i][j]=new Button(this);

                    rowLayout.addView(pBtnDay[i][j],param); 

                    pBtnDay[i][j].setOnLongClickListener(this);                         
                    pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);



                }
            }
            return true;
```

one more thing when i try to find width and height of the buttons it return 0..why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using weightSum is the best solution if you know exactly how many elements you want displayed on your screen, across multiple devices. So if it shows up on, say a HTC Wildfire(LDPI) then it will also show on your Nexus(HDPI).

As for your second question, I´m assuming you are using View.getHeight() and View.getWidth() to obtain these values. Since your buttons hasn´t actually been drawn yet, Android has not designated dimension values to them, that´s why they turn up 0. If you need the width and height of these buttons in onCreate, then you need to do some math of your own :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the basic philosophy in Adnroid Application is portability across platforms with different Screen Resolution, pixel depth and Oreintation.

How to achieve this, has been explained well in [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) link. Enjoy!

In case you are interested in getting Screen Parameters, then you can use DisplayMetrics and Window Manager. 
Shash

Answer (score 1):

For the second answer: if you need the button dimension values, use:

```
@Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
  {
      if (hasFocus)
      {
// calculates dimesions
      }
  }
```

In fact, as told before, in the onCreate you still have not calculate them.

Comment: That's right, when onWindowsFocusChanged fires Android has drawn out dimensions for your views.